# Set expiry time for fields on content type

Tags: entities

Is there a module which allows to set expiry date on fields on content type. Needed when we want a particular field to be expired after a given interval of time, not the complete node as in case of node expire module.

Comment: Check if the field_expire (https://drupal.org/project/field_expire) module works for you. The module can be cloned from git repos. https://drupal.org/project/field_expire/git-instructions

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Did you already use that module? Is it functional?

Comment: Sorry, but your question looks like you haven't even read the front page of a module you are mentioning :( If you did, and can't make it work, please tell us what have you tried and how it failed.

Comment: @Molot you are right my bad I didn try the module

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal thanks for sharing the link, I tried the mentioned module but its not in working state. As mentioned before node expire module is the best option I can see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First feature of [Node expire](https://drupal.org/project/node_expire) is:

> - Perform custom actions when the nodes expire

Just write a custom action that will change field's value instead of unpublishing node.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no such module. But since [Node Expire](https://drupal.org/project/node_expire) integrates with rules, I could imagine that you can configure the node to expire without unpublishing it and then react on the expiration by setting the field value of the field(s) in question to empty.

Comment: Seems we both wrote our answers at almost the same moment.

Comment: @Mołot yep ;) I was about 25 seconds faster :D